# Reset UIBezierPath dashed line to normal line

Tags: ios, uikit, uibezierpath

I know `UIBezierPath`'s `- (void)setLineDash:(const CGFloat *)pattern count:(NSInteger)count phase:(CGFloat)phase` method can draw dashed lines.

But how to reset it to normal line in programming?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will do it for you: `[instance setLineDash:nil count:0 phase:0];`